# How to breed a T-Rox

Tags: my-singing-monsters

I have been playing *My Singing Monsters* for a while and have tried to hatch a T-Rox by breeding a Potbelly and a Maw. The problem is, I keep getting a Bogart. I know for a fact that the potbelly and maw create a T-Rox. What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the wiki, the [T-Rox](http://mysingingmonsters.wikia.com/wiki/T-Rox) is Cold, Water, Earth. Your combination does not have Earth, but Plant instead, creating the [Bowgart](http://mysingingmonsters.wikia.com/wiki/Bowgart). (Your combination is the first example for creating a Bogart). Using a Noggin and Maw should work instead.